# Map "Ctrl + Left click" to "Go to definition" in Monodevelop

Tags: ide, keyboard-shortcuts, monodevelop

From Eclipse and IntelliJ I'm used to holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and left-clicking to `Go to definition`.

Monodevelop also provides a `Go to definition` feature, but I wasn't able to map it to my favorite <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ left-click. I know how to map actions to keyboard shortcuts in Monodevelop, but it seems that there is no way to use mouse clicks in these mappings.

Any idea how to get this working? Or maybe there is a plugin for that?

Comment: I would be interested in that too.

Comment: Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this in MonoDevelop. I have looked for an add-on too, but I found none.

Comment: Kind of sad that this has to be the accepted answer ;-)

Comment: Is this still true?

Answer (score 0):

In monodevelop 7.8 this option is exist. Edit/Preferences/Key Bindings, then search "go to declaration" You can find it there. F12 is default key. I'm an old eclipse user and I used F3. I changed F3 the shortcut and I become happy :)